# IF condition in bash

Tags: bash

I have just started learning to write bash scripts. This a simplified form of what I want to write.
The problem is despite of the input, it prints only "YES".

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
read input

if (("$input"== "y" || "$input" == "Y"))
then
   echo "YES";    
elif (("$input" == "n" || "$input" == "N"))
then
     echo "NO";
else
    echo "Not a valid input!!"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[[` instead of `((` like,

```
if [[ "$input" == "y" || "$input" == "Y" ]]
```

and also  there must be a space exists before `==` operator.

ie,

```
input="n"
if [[ "$input" == "y" || "$input" == "Y" ]]
then
   echo "YES";    
elif [[ "$input" == "n" || "$input" == "N" ]]
then
     echo "NO";
else
    echo "Not a valid input!!"
fi
```

You could use regular expression also for condition checking purpose.

```
if [[ "$input" =~ ^[yY]$ ]]
then
   echo "YES";    
elif [[ "$input" =~ ^[nN]$ ]]
then
     echo "NO";
else
    echo "Not a valid input!!"
fi
```

Comment: To expand on this: `(( ))` gets you an arithmetic expression, so it's comparing `"$input"` and `"y"` *as numbers*, which doesn't make any sense. `[[ ]]`, on the other hand, is a conditional expression, and `==` in that context does string comparison. Note that you can also do numeric comparison in a conditional expression, but with `-eq` instead of `==`.

Comment: You can also use pattern matching ( `[[ $input = [Yy] ]]`) which is a little simpler than the equivalent regular expression. There is also a way to enable case-insensitive matching, but it's probably not worth the effort just to allow `[[ $input = Y ]]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you automaticly convert the input to lowercase (using typeset), you do not have to bother with the the uppercases.
When you use an elif, always think 10 seconds for another solution. In this case you might want to use a "switch", in shell written as a case-statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
typeset -l input
read input
case ${input} in 
   "y") echo "Yes";;
   "n") echo "NO";;
   *)   echo "Not a valid input!!";;
esac
```